# keyof T doesn't appear as a string subtype within mapped types

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1

The following snippet fails on the assignment of `y` due to incompatible types:

```
function foo<T>() {
    let x: { [P in keyof T]: number }
    let y: { [k: string]: number } = x;
}
```

However, the documentation states:

> A keyof T type is considered a subtype of string.

If that was true, why does the assignment fail?

Assigning a `keyof T` to a `string` works, and assigning a `{ [P in 'foo']: number }` to `{ [P in string]: number }` also works.

Comment: it might be a bug. try filing it on their issue tracker if you haven't already. if/when they reply, answer your own question here cause i wanna know :)

Comment: [I did](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14625#issuecomment-286182691) and it was marked as a duplicate (but still open).