# A variable typed as keyof T used as a dynamic property results in an implicit string-index type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a complex use-case, so I've written the following MCVE:

```js
function createSeedMap<T extends (...args:any)=>any>(seedKey:keyof T, seedValue:string):void {
    // ...

    const seedMap:Record<keyof T, string> = {
        [seedKey]: seedValue,
    };

    // ...
}
```

The important piece here is the `seedMap` variable (the function is just to demonstrate the issue).

I have a variable (`seedKey`, in this case) that is simply typed as `keyof T` and I am using it as a dynamic property in an object initializer which is assigned to a variable (`seedMap`) typed as `Record<keyof T, string>`.

It is important for other parts of my code (not shown) to keep the `seedKey` variable type as `keyof T`. As I need to later reference properties of `seedMap` using `seedKey`, changing these types would introduce a lot of type assertions that I would prefer to avoid.

This seems pretty straight forward and I didn't expect any errors, but the result is the following:

```
Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<keyof T, string>'.
```

For some reason I don't fully understand, my `keyof T` (which could be a symbol, by the way!) is interpreted as a `string` in the object initializer. The TypeScript compiler complains that an object with a *string* index (again... `seedKey` is `keyof T` which could be a symbol!) can't be assigned to a Record with a `keyof T` index.

I thought I might be able to fix this like so:

```js
function createSeedMap<T extends (...args:any)=>any>(seedKey:keyof T, seedValue:string):void {
    // ...

    const seedMap:Record<keyof T, string> = {};

    seedMap[seedKey] = seedValue;

    // ...
}
```

But now I get the following error:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Record<keyof T, string>'.
```

So now I think the issue might be that I'm using `keyof T` as an index for `Record`. Perhaps this introduces a lot of unsupported scenarios?

I've tried to find some confirmation of this limitation and a reasonable workaround (that hopefully doesn't involve type assertions), but so far I've only found the following Q/A's which either don't address this specific issue (as best I can tell) or are unanswered:

- [Typescript generic type - Type 'keyof T1' cannot be used to index type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470907/typescript-generic-type-type-keyof-t1-cannot-be-used-to-index-type)
- [How to declare a "Record" type with partial of specific keys in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950470/how-to-declare-a-record-type-with-partial-of-specific-keys-in-typescript)
- [TypeScript: Indexing into an object type using keyof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941672/typescript-indexing-into-an-object-type-using-keyof)
- [keyof T doesn't appear as a string subtype within mapped types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753331/keyof-t-doesnt-appear-as-a-string-subtype-within-mapped-types)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I am using TypeScript 4.8.4 and have [confirmed these issues in the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQZTWgEwFkMAHAHgBVE0APbMAgZ0QAoA6TjFAcyYC4MYAJ4BKALwA+IcMmsm+AgGk0w-gGtVcYIkoAaRAsIA1DABsQafkygoYYHqP4A3ODAKIA3gFgAUIgDEAHogxE52Pz9A5AQbQ0USUn4AJTQIOBQCck1hbV0DGzsHSURxLyjowIBtI2VVAF1+eJNzSz0KgIBfAG5I-0CQsM4-TqA), so I'm sure it's not a local config issue.

Answer (score 0):

After yet more experimenting, I think I found a solution, helped along by TS Playground's intellisense:

[image: Monaco editor displays intellisense showing that seedKey is a string or number or symbol rather than keyof T]

I changed `Record<keyof T,...` to `Record<string|number|symbol...` and this appears to have worked for my specific situation.

It still doesn't explain why `keyof T` was such a problem. (Why was the type system able to recognize that `seedKey` must be a `string|number|symbol` in some contexts but not others?)

However, as this solved the issue for me, I'll post it as an answer in case it is helpful to anyone else. (I would still be grateful for any answers that explain this more fully)